# How do you segue in a mac application without creating a new window?

Tags: swift, macos, view, segue

I'm trying to segue to the bottom view controller after hitting the submit button, but when I do it creates a new window.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvGcj.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one of the default behaviour of Cocoa segues. One solution is to close the previous window when moving through the segue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    self.view.window?.close()
    //Pass data to new view
}
```

I have just found [this tutorial](http://theiconmaster.com/2015/03/transitioning-between-view-controllers-in-the-same-window-with-swift-mac/) and the developer creates a very interesting transition effect, take a look at the source code at the bottom of the page

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it is what I was looking for. Will come back once I've had a chance to try the code.

Comment: Confirming in 2019 that this works great. Just need to update to the latest Swift.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. If you have a spare time please edit the post with the latest Swift snippet, I will accept the changes ASAP. Otherwise, I will try to update it in the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which relies extensively on [this Extelligent Cocoa blog post](https://www.extelligentcocoa.org/macos-storyboard-segues/), in particular the use of the "Tabless `TabViewController`".  This solution avoids both having to reference the `First Responder` (as is done in the blog post) and having to manually instantiate View Controllers (as is discussed [on the Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/14485)).  Segues are managed by the storyboard and achieve the same effect as a full-screen `Present Modally` segue would in iOS - as intended.

Please refer to the Extelligent Cocoa post linked above for the details on configuring the NSTabViewController to be tabless.

Here is the code from the parent TabViewController (make sure to check the box for "Is Initial Controller" in the Attributes Inspector):

```
import Cocoa

class TabViewController: NSTabViewController {
    let screens = ["Screen1": 0, "Screen2": 1]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        K.globalVars.parentViewController = self
    }
    
    func switchScreens(to screenName: String, _ sender: Any) {
        selectedTabViewItemIndex = screens[screenName]!
    }
}
```

The first child ViewController:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController1: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func goForward(_ sender: NSButton) {
        K.globalVars.parentViewController!.switchScreens(to: "Screen2", self)
    }
}
```

And the second child ViewController:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController2: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func goBack(_ sender: NSButton) {
        K.globalVars.parentViewController!.switchScreens(to: "Screen1", self)
    }
}
```

As there doesn't seem to be a built-in way to access the parent `NSTabViewController` from the child `NSViewController`s, it is necessary to store a reference to it somewhere in the global scope.  I have done so in a Constants.swift file:

```
import Cocoa

struct K {
    struct globalVars {
        static var parentViewController: TabViewController?
    }
}
```

Here is the storyboard, shown below.  When you press the Forward button on Screen 1, it transitions to Screen 2 within the same window.  When you press the Back button on Screen 2, it goes back to Screen 1.

[image]